# SELECT / Querying "into" JSON arrays

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, squirrel-sql

I have a PostgreSQL 9.4.5 database. There's a table `itemtable` with a JSONB column called `data`, which contains sets of information like so (lots of stuff stripped for brevity):

```
{ "items": [
    { "id": 158597 },
    { "id": 156300 },
    (...)
] }
```

Now, I want to get a list of all the `id`s in those sets of items - informally one might say `SELECT id FROM items FROM data FROM itemtable`. I've only managed to do that using a subquery, which is obviously suboptimal:

```
SELECT idlist->>'id' FROM ( 
   SELECT json_array_elements(data::json->'items') AS idlist FROM itemtable 
) AS necessary_subquery_name
```

How can I do that less convoluted?

Please note that I'd need to run this in SquirrelSQL, so the `::json` cast is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh well, nevermind, I must have missed a coffee today. It's obviously:

```
SELECT json_array_elements(data::json->'items')->>'id' FROM itemtable
```